# Updating AngularJS bindings and query from cache after deleting expanded item

Tags: javascript, angularjs, breeze

Please reference [***this question***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20541415/breezejs-getentitybykey-with-expand) as background.

After running a query that includes an expand to get related entities, if one then deletes one of the expanded entities, how is the breeze cache updated?

I ask this, because (per the recommended solution to the referenced question), I am finding that if I query from cache after deleting an expanded item, the item still appears unless I force a call to the server.

this is the function i'm currently using to retrieve from cache if available or the server if not. I am forcing a call to this function after my delete.

```
function _getByIdExpanded(resource, id, expand, forceRefresh) {
    var self = this;

    if (!forceRefresh) {
        var entity = self.em.getEntityByKey(resource, id);
        if (entity && entity.isReadyForEdit) {
            //logSuccess('Retrieved ' + resource + ' ' + entity.name + ' from cache', entity, true);
            if (entity.entityAspect.entityState.isDeleted()) {
                entity = null;
            }
            return self.$q.when(entity);
        }
    }

    return eq.from(resource + 's') //pluralise for table name in DB
        .where('id', '==', id)
        .expand(expand)
        .using(self.em).execute()
        .to$q(succeeded, self._failed);

    function succeeded(data) {
        var result = data.results;
        entity = result[0];
        if (!entity) {
            logError('Could not find ' + resource + ' with id: ' + id, null);
            return null;
        }
        entity.isReadyForEdit = true;
        //logSuccess('Retrieved ' + resource + ' ' + entity.name + ' from server', entity, true);
        return entity;
    }
}
```

---

EDIT:

Ok, after some tests, it appears my error is actually an Angular one not a breeze one.

Here are the two calls in my controller that are related:

```
function deleteEntity(entity) {
    return bsDialog.deleteDialog(entity.name).then(function () {
        datacontext.markDeleted(entity);
        save().then(function () {
            if (entity.entityType === dboardConfigEntity) {
                $location.path('/subscriber/' + subscriberId);
            } else { getDboardConfig(true); } // forcing call back to server for testing
        });
    });
}

function getDboardConfig(forceRefresh) {
    if ($routeParams.newOrExisting === 'new') {
        subscriberId = $routeParams.id;
        return vm.dboardConfig = datacontext.dboardConfigs.create(subscriberId);
    }
    return datacontext.dboardConfigs.getByIdExpanded($routeParams.id, forceRefresh)
        .then(function (data) {
        vm.dboardConfig = data;
        subscriberId = vm.dboardConfig.subscriberId;
        vm.hideChildren = false;
    });
}
```

This call is just a pass-through to an abstract repository (which contains the function in my first post above):

```
function getByIdExpanded(id, forceRefresh) {
    var expand = 'Dims';
    return this._getByIdExpanded(entityName, id, expand, forceRefresh);
}
```

This is my delete and save calls in my datacontext:

```
function markDeleted(entity) {
    return entity.entityAspect.setDeleted();
}

function save() {
    return em.saveChanges()
    .to$q(saveSucceeded, saveFailed);

    function saveSucceeded(result) {
        logSuccess('Successfully saved to the server', result, true);
        return result;
    }

    function saveFailed(error) {
        var msg = config.appErrorPrefix + 'Failed to save changes to the server. '
            + breeze.saveErrorMessageService.getErrorMessage(error);
        error.message = msg;
        logError(msg, error);
        throw error;
    }
}
```

An extract from my markup:

```
<table class="table table-condensed table-striped" data-ng-show="vm.dboardConfig.dims.length > 0">
    <thead>
        <th>{{dt.name}}</th>
        <th></th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr data-ng-repeat="d in vm.dboardConfig.dims | filter:{ dimTypeId: dt.id }">
            <td>{{d.name}}</td>
            <td>
                <div class="pull-right">
                   <a href="" data-ng-click="vm.edit(d)">
                        <i class="fa fa-pencil blue"></i>
                   </a>
                   <a href="" data-ng-click="vm.delete(d)">
                        <i class="fa fa-times-circle red"></i>
                   </a>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
     </tbody>
</table>
```

As far as I can see, I'm resolving all my promises returned form the query, so why are the elements in my table not updating unless I refresh?

---

FURTHER EDIT:

After running through the browser debugger, what I'm noticing is that even though I have marked the expanded child entity for deletion and saved, when I run the query to retrieve the updated entity, the expanded child is still included, but in a detached state, indicating that breeze has saved the deletion. After reviewing some of the Breeze documentation on this, the question then comes down to this - How do I adjust my code so that Angular doesn't bind detached entities? My understanding was previously that Angular would not display detached entities, but for some reason it is...

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so after scouring posts on SO, finally came across [***this one***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21135013/breeze-behavior-of-setdeleted/21144498#21144498).

For those interested, the problem in my case was being caused by Breeze. All my code above seems to be okay.

However, my original class design for  Dim (my "expanded" entity) was...

```
public class Dim
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int DboardConfigId { get; set; }
    public int DimTypeId { get; set; }
    public DimType DimType { get; set; }
}
```

The entity had no navigation property back to DboardConfig. Becuase I had no need to navigate to any of DboardConfig's properties, I decided this was unecessary. However, as it happens, it appears that lacking the navigation property causes the problem described in my question. so by adding a property `public DboardConfig DboardConfig { get; set; }` to the class, the problem disappeared.

I'd be curious to understand why Breeze needs this navigation property for deleting expanded items and having them reflect in the binding?

Comment: I don't think this was a Breeze issue - Breeze uses the metadata provided to it.  In your case your model wasn't properly set up to handle cascading deletions.  Have you looked in to FluentApi configuration - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591617.aspx

Comment: @PWKad at length, and typically fluent api is only really needed if you dont follow convention which I do in this case and cascading is enabled in the db. However, I dont require cascading here as im deleting a child with no intention of deleting its parent. The point of my answer is that without navigation properties in the child (which arent required for the model) angular bindings are not updating and Angular is reliant on what's passed back from the breeze promise. So there is an anomoly of sorts

Comment: When deleting an expanded entity, breeze needs to know which parent it came from because it's "expanded". The serialized object is an entity with it's child array, that child array should refer to it's parent for the sake of deleting. Glad you managed to solve it.

Comment: @adelSal yes, i can understand this, but it already has the parent's id, it should be uneccessary to also have the navigation unless you want to reach the parent's properties. Unless, of course, the rationale is that the `icollection<child>` needs to be updated within the parent and its for this reason that the navigation is thus needed.